# How to insert another webform record inside current webform and go back to previous page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two webform diagnosis webform and bill webform .
In diagnosis webform i have patient name , diagnosis detail and billId . In Bill webform I have BillId billAmount
which i want is that i want to save patient diagnosis info by click button_click event . after clicking i want to redirect billId page and save bill info . then go back to previous page and save patient diagnosis info with billId . 
How to do that ?

Comment: But you saved diagnosis info already so why do you want to go back and save it again?

Comment: I want to save diagnosis with bill Id

Answer (score 0):

Put your data inside Session State. You can acces it from any form.[Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_managing_state.htm)